# How to detect language or script from an input image using Python or Tesseract OCR?

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

Given an input image which can be in any language or writing system, how do I detect what script the text in the picture uses?

Any Python-based or Tesseract-OCR based solution would be appreciated.

---

Note that script here means writing systems like *Latin, Cyrillic, Devanagari, etc.*, for corresponding languages like *English, Russian, Hindi, etc.* (respectively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pre-requisites:**

- Install Tesseract: `sudo apt install tesseract-ocr tesseract-ocr-all`
- Install PyTessract: `pip install pytesseract`

**Script-Detection:**

```py
import pytesseract
import re

def detect_image_lang(img_path):
    try:
        osd = pytesseract.image_to_osd(img_path)
        script = re.search("Script: ([a-zA-Z]+)\n", osd).group(1)
        conf = re.search("Script confidence: (\d+\.?(\d+)?)", osd).group(1)
        return script, float(conf)
    except e:
        return None, 0.0

script_name, confidence = detect_image_lang("image.png")
```

**Language-Detection:**

After performing OCR ([using Tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37745519)), pass the text [through `langdetect` library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64402156) (or any other lib).

Comment: [Check here for list of all scripts & languages supported by Tesseract OCR](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files-in-different-versions.html).