# how to detect the unknow text language in a image?

Tags: python, ocr, language-detection, ocrmypdf

I have N number of scanned images. the images contain different languages like Chinese, Arabic and Japanese. I tried to do OCR process for the files using OCRMYPDF and tesseract. both required the language of the input file. But I don't know the language of the file. So, Now my question is how to identify the languages used in a image ?

Comment: You can look at [this question in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70198974/how-to-detect-language-or-script-from-an-input-image-using-python-or-tesseract-o)

Comment: No. The answer you mentioned will give the script of the text not language of the text.